# Setting Email Notification for Virtual machine whic are down or services that are stopped in Azure Cloud

Tags: email, virtual-machines, azure

We have more than 10 virtual machines in our cloud environment.there are some duration during which our virtual machine get stopped or the services get automatically stopped. We tried with creating rules, but it only works for a particular threshold. I want to set email notifications, if any of the virtual machine is down, or services get stopped. is it possible in the azure cloud environment.

Comment: So your problem is. Are you not able to stop services/vms on some periods? Or, are you not able to set notifications when these services/vms are not up && running out of these periods?

Comment: I want email notification in any case, if the virtual machine gets down or services get stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any third party monitoring software tools like PandoraFMS to monitor any services and virtual machine uptime. You will get many options to monitor various services like:

MS SQL server (on port 3306), 
MySQL server (on port 1433), 
IIS/Apache web server (on port 80) and 
Server Uptime (on time ICMP package - Ping).

You can also set email notifications on services or server down incidents.